# Syntax for POSTing Parameters via Alamofire + Swift 2

Tags: swift, alamofire

The error reads: "Value of optional type String? is unwrapped. Did you mean to use ! or ?". Attempting to correct the error via Xcode doesn't solve the problem.

```
import Alamofire
import UIKit

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {  

    @IBOutlet weak var usernametextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordtextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailtextfield: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let usernameInput = self.usernametextfield.text
            let passwordInput = self.passwordtextfield.text
            let emailInput = self.emailtextfield.text

            // thanks Michael
            let parameters : [ String : AnyObject?] = ["hashword":passwordInput, "email":emailInput, "username":usernameInput]

            // but now..
            Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://my-ip/api/users", parameters:parameters).responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, _) -> Void in
```

Edit: one step further but the very next line says: Cannot convert value of type '[String : AnyObject?]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]?'

The last lines of code from the view did load block are:

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://my-ip/api/users", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
    let translatedText: String? = JSON?.valueForKeyPath("responseData.translatedText") as String?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared parameters as `AnyObject`, but you're trying to put Optionals into it. You can put `!` on the variables that are Optionals (UITextField.text is an Optional String):

```
let parameters : [ String : AnyObject] = ["hashword":passwordInput!, "email":emailInput!, "username":usernameInput!]
```

Note that this will crash if any of them contain nil.

Alternatively, since all your parameters are Optional Strings, you could declare parameters the same:

```
let parameters : [ String : String?] = ["hashword":passwordInput, "email":emailInput, "username":usernameInput]
```

EDIT: Since you're using Alamofire that requires parameters to be defined as `[String : AnyObject]?` you could use:

```
let parameters : [ String : AnyObject] = ["hashword":passwordInput ?? "", "email":emailInput ?? "", "username":usernameInput ?? ""]
```

This will use the value (eg. passwordInput) if it's not nil, or an empty string otherwise.